# On the conditions of a Riemann integral substitution

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Consider the following statement:

> Consider two functions $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ and $\phi:[c,d]\to [a,b]$ with the following properties:
>   1)$f$ is continuous
>   2)$\phi$ is bijective, $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are differentiable and their derivatives are continuous.
>   Then $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_{\phi^{-1}(a)}^{\phi^{-1}(b)}f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt.$$

The proof given in my textbook goes as follows:
Let $F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be an antiderivative of $f$ (it exists since $f$ is continuous). Then $\int_a^b f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)(1)$.
By the chain rule, we have that $(F\circ \phi)'(t)=F'(\phi(t))\phi'(t)=f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)$, which shows that $F\circ \phi$ is an antiderivative of $(f\circ \phi)\cdot \phi'$.
As a result, $\int_{\phi^{-1}(a)}^{\phi^{-1}(b)}f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt=(F\circ \phi)(t) |_{\phi^{-1}(a)}^{\phi^{-1}(b)}=F(b)-F(a)(2)$.
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we reach the desired conclusion.
My question is: why is it necessary that $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ have continuous derivatives? Wouldn't it be enough if they were just Riemann integrable?

Comment: Well the most general result for substitution is as follows: assume that function $h$ is Riemann integrable on $[c, d] $ and $g(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} h(t) \, dt$ for some fixed $a\in[c, d] $. If the function $f$ is Riemann integrable on $g([c, d]) $ then we have $\int_{g(c)} ^{g(d)} f(x) \, dx=\int_{c} ^{d} f(g(t)) h(t) \, dt$. To simplify things a bit the substitution $x=g(t) $ works if $g$ has a Riemann integrable derivative. And $g$ need not be invertible.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you ! I also suspected that it worked in the conditions that I mentioned. Shouldn't $g$ be invertible, though? The new integration limits should be in terms of $t$ and I don't see how they may be obtained if $g$ is not invertible.

Comment: You need to solve $a=g(c), b=g(d) $ and find $c, d$. One does not $g$ to be invertible for solving this. Invertible is needed to guarantee uniqueness of solutions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I agree, I think that injectivity would be enough. But what if $g$ is not injective and $g(c)=a$ for instance has two solutions, which one will be the correct integration limit?

Comment: Both solutions would work fine. Note that $g$ is continuous and differentiable and it's derivative is Riemann integrable.